Navbar pops up when DropdownMenu from material3 appears on MIUI
I have Activity with hidden navigation bar and pure Compose content. It works as expected until androidx.compose.material3.DropdownMenu is shown. At this moment navbar is back, it hides again when menu is closed: GIF1. Then I did DropdownMenu(properties = PopupProperties(dismissOnBackPress = false)). Now navbar pops up when menu appears and quickly hides back on its own with animation: GIF2.
@Composable
fun MenuSample(onSearch: () -> Unit) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    DropdownMenu(
        expanded = expanded,
        onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
        properties = PopupProperties(dismissOnBackPress = false)
    ) {
        DropdownMenuItem(
            text = { Text("Search") },
            onClick = onSearch,
            leadingIcon = {
                Icon(
                    Icons.Outlined.Search,
                    contentDescription = null
                )
            })
    }
}

Navbar absence is initially configured like this:

class MyActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Companion.window = window
        hideNavBarAgain()
        setContent { MyJetpackContent() }
    }

    companion object { //for experimentation purposes
        var window: Window? = null

        fun hideNavBarAgain() {
            WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window!!, window!!.decorView).let { controller ->
                controller.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars())
                controller.systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
            }
        }
    }
}

So far I tried

dismiss-false -- properties = PopupProperties(dismissOnBackPress = false) as DropdownMenu argument (my original finding)
SideEffect -- SideEffect { MyActivity.hideNavBarAgain() } (suggested by @rafael-moreira), in every composable scope possible of MenuSample and also around it.
remCorSc.launch -- rememberCoroutineScope.launch { MyActivity.hideNavBarAgain() } in user click lambda that enables Menu. Also without coroutine scope in same place.
onPlaced -- Modifier.onPlaced { MyActivity.hideNavBarAgain() } for both DropdownMenu and DropdownMenuItem

Experiments matrix (navbar hidden in OnCreate() in all cases):



dismiss-false
SideEffect
remCorSc.launch
onPlaced
outcome




➖
➖
➖
➖
 permanent navbar GIF1


➕
➖
➖
➖
 jumpy navbar GIF2


➖
➕
➖
➖
 permanent navbar


➖
➖
➕
➖
 permanent navbar


➕
➕
➕
➕
 jumpy navbar



It worth nothing, that all this is happening on MIUI 13. On relatively pure Android 14 (Nothing OS) none of this happens! 0 workarounds (➖|➖|➖) give missing navbar as expected, MyActivity config is enough.
How do I properly prevent navbar from showing at first place for all platforms?

It's because DropDownMenu is considered a Pop-up in terms of behaviour. It's like the user is interacting with the screen.
Use the composable SideEffect to create a reaction with the DropDownMenu (from MenuSample) when is shown or not, to avoid displaying your navigation bar.
EXAMPLE:
Add SideEffect to your MenuSample function and the window object as a parameter when you call MenuSample.
For more details, check the documentation.
@Composable
fun MenuSample(onSearch: () -> Unit, window: Window) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    SideEffect {
     WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView).let { controller ->
        controller.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars())
        controller.systemBarsBehavior = 
           WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
     }
    }

    DropdownMenu(
        expanded = expanded,
        onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
        properties = PopupProperties(dismissOnBackPress = false)
    ) {
        DropdownMenuItem(
            text = { Text("Search") },
            onClick = onSearch,
            leadingIcon = {
                Icon(
                    Icons.Outlined.Search,
                    contentDescription = null
                )
            })
    }
}


I appreciate suggestion and especially example, but it does not affect the issue at all. I updated the question with more details and pics, pls check

@multistackdeveloper Have you tried a simple conditional to hidenavbaragain() when expanded?

I did tried triggering without conditions, like, everywhere, Ill share the code a tomorrow. It is obvsl hidden again by system almost immediately, it mostly animation lag.
You just gave me an idea to look for some listeners or open methods in activity to capture "intent" of showing navbar, probably I can cancel it from there. It's so frustrating when such small things consume so much time :(

@multistackdeveloper If it's open source, please, share the repo and maybe we can figure it out.
